# Azure replication of a physical server

Tags: azure, replication

Can Azure replication replicate a physical server, or does it only replicate the VMs on that server?

Answer (score 1):

It can: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/migrate-tutorial-on-premises-azure

> This tutorial shows you how to migrate on-premises VMs and **physical servers** to Azure.